# How to limit the number of elements in a droppable list?

Tags: jquery, limit, element, droppable

could any one of you help me modify my code to limit the number of elements in a droppable list to accept only one item, and to show a message if the user try to drop more than one item?

Here is my code

```
$("#droppable_widget,#draggable_widgets").sortable({
            connectWith: "#droppable_widget,#draggable_widgets",
            start: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
            }
});
```

Comment: Why not just unbind the _droppable_ event after the first item is dropped?

Comment: Would you please show me how to do that?.. I am not a jquery expert :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return false whenever the conditions arise where you want to abort the event. Something like this seems to fit the bill, is that about what you want?
http://jsfiddle.net/tBaHd/1/

```
$("#droppable_widget,#draggable_widget").sortable({
  connectWith: "#droppable_widget,#draggable_widget",
  start: function (event, ui) {
  },
  stop: function (event, ui) {
    var item = $(ui.item);
    var to = item.parent().is("#droppable_widget");
    var siblingsCount = item.siblings().size();
    if (to && siblingsCount > 0) {
      alert("only one item allowed here");
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#droppable_widget,#draggable_widgets").sortable({
            connectWith: "#droppable_widget,#draggable_widgets",
            start: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
                    $('#droppable_widget').droppable('disable');
            }
});
```

Comment: It should keep you from dropping more than one item, does it not?